# MongoDB return codes meaning (ruby driver)

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm calling collection update from ruby driver to mongodb and gets a return code 117.
How do I generally interpret the error codes that I get?

Comment: Good question. I'd start looking at ruby driver's source code.

Comment: can you include the snippet of your code that returns this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using safe mode, the update method returns a hash containing the output of getLastError. However, when you are not using safe mode, we simply return the number of bytes that were sent to the server.

```
# setup connection & get handle to collection
connection = Mongo::Connection.new
collection = connection['test']['test']

# remove existing documents
collection.remove
=> true

# insert test document
collection.insert(:_id => 1, :a => 1)
=> 1
collection.find_one
=> {"_id"=>1, "a"=>1}

# we sent a message with 64 bytes to a mongod
collection.update({_id: 1},{a: 2.0})
=> 64 # number of bytes sent to server

# with safe mode we updated one document -- output of getLastError command
collection.update({_id: 1},{a: 3.0}, :safe => true)
=> {"updatedExisting"=>true, "n"=>1, "connectionId"=>19, "err"=>nil, "ok"=>1.0}
```

This is something that could be made clearer in the documentation. I will update it for the next ruby driver release.